# Image of a finite dimensional complex representations of $GL_n(\mathcal{O})$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups, non-archimedean-fields

**EDIT** Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the ring of integers in a non-Archimedean local field. Let $GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ be the (compact) group of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathcal{O}$ such that its inverse also has entries in $\mathcal{O}$.

> Consider a continuous finite dimensional representation of $GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ in a **complex** vector space $V$. Is it true that the image of $GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ in $GL(V)$ is a finite subgroup?

A reference would be most helpful.

Comment: With which topology is the vector space equipped ?

Comment: Standard complex topology which is unique on any finite dimensional complex vector space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the representation $\pi$.  Let $U$ be a neighbourhood of the identity in $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ that contains no non-trivial subgroup.  Then the pre-image of $U$ under $\pi$ is a neighbourhood of the identity there, hence contains some open subgroup.  That is, $\ker(\pi)$ contains an open subgroup, hence is open, hence has finite index.  The representation thus factors through the finite quotient $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathcal O)/\ker(\pi)$.

Comment: Many thanks. Is there a reference to this (despite it is simple)?

Comment: @MKO, some good places to look for questions like this are [DeBacker's notes on representations of $p$-adic groups](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~smdbackr/MATH/notes.pdf), [Casselman's $p$-adic book](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/p-adic-book.pdf), and [Bernstein and Zelevinsky - Induced representations of reductive $\mathfrak p$-adic groups. I](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=ASENS_1977_4_10_4_441_0) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=579172)).  Unfortunately, in this case it seems that none of them has it.

Comment: @MKO, I'd also consult [Jacquet - Sur les représentations des groups réductifs $p$-adiques](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=369624), but I don't have a copy and it doesn't seem to be online.